# JS click events not working for pausing css animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know it is a little messy so if anyone has a better solution would be great, but any ideas why the click events are not working? and also am i doing it right to pause and resume? oh plus does anyone know a good way to restart as not done that bit either.

Thanks for all your help

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uj4e5cw0/2/

JS:

```
var playing = false;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var svgPath = $("#ring");

         $("#pause").on("click", function () {
            $(svgPath).removeClass("active");
            $(svgPath).addClass("paused");
        });

        $("#resume").on("click", function () {
            $(svgPath).removeClass("paused");
            $(svgPath).addClass("active");
        });

        $("#restart").on("click", function () {

        });

        $('#loader').on("click", function () {
            if (!playing) {
                $("svg path").attr("class", "active");
                /* $("#circle").attr("class", "active"); */
                $("svg path#back").attr("stroke", "#034870");
                $("svg path#back").attr("fill", "#FFFFFF");
                $("svg path#ring").attr("stroke", "#FF1251");
                playing = true;
            }
            else {
                $("svg path").attr("class", "");
                /* $("#circle").attr("class", ""); */
                playing = false;
            }

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working.
What I found was that the click events were not changing the classes.
Using `addClass` and `removeClass` just didn't want to work using `.attr` as you did to start the animation worked a treat.

```
    $("body").on("click", "#pause",function () {
        $("svg path").attr("class", "active paused");
    });

    $("body").on("click", "#resume", function () {
        $("svg path").attr("class", "active");
    });

    $("#restart").on("click", function () {
        $("svg path").attr("class", "");
    });
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/uj4e5cw0/4/)

Comment: Thanks mate, yea i just saw that when using SVG you need to use attr and cannot use addClass or removeClass..... Thanks for helping